# Can I combine these two arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, export-to-csv

I have some simple Exchange Powershell I have written. I would like to list the UPN, Displayname, Item Count, and Item Size into a single CSV. However I have only been able to successfully push the data to two arrays and then manually combine them. Here is my code.

```
$MailBoxs = Get-Mailbox * | Select UserPrincipalName -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName | Sort-Object UserPrincipalName
$Mailboxs2 = $MailBoxs.Where({ $_ -ne $null })
ForEach($MailBox2 in $MailBoxs2) { Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox2 | Sort-Object TotalItemSize –Descending | Select @{label=”User”;expression={$_.DisplayName}},@{label=”Total Size (MB)”;expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}},@{label=”Items”;expression={$_.ItemCount}} | Export-CSV "C:\T2\MailBoxSize.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation }
ForEach($MailBox2 in $MailBoxs2) { $Mailbox2 | Export-CSV "C:\T2\MailBoxSize2.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation }
```

Basically the second CSV gives me two fields for some reason the SMTP address and some random Length field, It also gives me a leading whitespace. If anyone has any ideas on how to clean this up I would love to hear them. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multiple select statements were unnecessary. Here's a bit simplified way:

```
$mailboxes = @(Get-Mailbox *).
    Where({$_.UserPrincipalName}) |
    Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName

foreach ($box in $mailboxes) {
    Get-MailboxStatistics $box.UserPrincipalName |
        Sort-Object -Property TotalItemSize -Descending |
        Select-Object -Property @(
            @{L='UPN';E={$box.UserPrincipalName}}
            @{L='User';E={$_.DisplayName}}
            @{L='Total Size (MB)';E={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}}
            @{L='Items';E={$_.ItemCount}}
        ) |
        Export-Csv -Path 'C:\T2\MailBoxSize.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: Your code is defiantly cleaner but it adds things I don't need and also I did a poor job of explaining what I was looking for so I apologize for that

Comment: @JRN See my edit.  I've updated the code to reflect your intention in that suggestion.

Comment: You are a gentlemen and a scholar. Thank you sir exactly what I needed. Thanks again for all your help.